# UserForm in script run from Outlook Rule

Tags: vba, outlook, userform, outlook-2007

Based on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306108 I'd like to create a custom rule that shows a custom UserForm instead of the plain old MsgBox.  What I wrote was this:

```
Dim alerts As CustomAlerts

Sub CustomMailMessageRule(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
   alerts.Messages.AddItem Item.Subject
   alerts.Show
End Sub
```

CustomAlerts is a UserForm containing a single ListBox.

Sadly my attempt does not work -- no window appears.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of your UserForm

Set alerts = new CustomAlerts

Marcus